# Extract motion vectors from x265 (HEVC) encoded video with ffmpeg/libavcodec?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, libx265

I know that one can extract the motion vectors from an h264 encoded via by first setting the flag

```
av_dict_set(&opts, "flags2", "+export_mvs", 0);
```

then you can query the side-data for the motion vectors by doing this

```
sd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);
```

When I looked online to see if you can do something similar with HEVC encoded videos, I wasn't able to find any information. All I found was this by the definition of "AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS"

> Motion vectors exported by some codecs (on demand through the
>   export_mvs flag set in the libavcodec AVCodecContext flags2 option).
>
> The data is the AVMotionVector struct defined in
>   libavutil/motion_vector.h.

but there was no information on exactly which codecs export this motion vector information. How would I go about finding this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken h264 is the only codec to print Motion Estimation Vectors.

I would suggest trying out the video filter [mestimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#mestimate).

Also, if you want to have a better ideia what's going on in ffmpeg, check the function ***ff_print_debug_info2*** in **libavcodec/mpegvideo.c**

Comment: To be clear, do you think that I could use the mestimate filter to force h265 encoded video to export the motion vectors in the side-data? Thanks for the response btw

Comment: @JohnAllard Yes, mestimate does exactly that, it will add motion vectors values to sidedata. I don't really know the use case of your solution but I should tell you that it's a bit of a slow process.

Comment: BTW, mestimate is quite new, so use the latest versions